# На что влияет атрибут SDL_GL_RED_SIZE?

Tags: opengl, color, sdl

В Wiki SDL нашел описание:

> SDL_GL_RED_SIZE - the minimum number of bits for the red channel of
> the color buffer; defaults to 3

Так и не понял, на что влияет этот параметр. Да, и что это за цветовой буфер (color buffer)?

Есть еще три атрибута: `SDL_GL_BLUE_SIZE`, `SDL_GL_GREEN`, `SDL_GL_ALPHA`.

Могу только предположить, что это `RGBA` и данные атрибуты влияют на количество отображаемых цветов. Надеюсь, более компетентные программисты просветят меня на этот счет.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сам нашел ответ на вопрос:

Аттрибуты `SDL_GL_RED_SIZE, SDL_GL_BLUE_SIZE, SDL_GL_GREEN_SIZE, SDL_GL_ALPHA_SIZE` влияют на *глубину цвета*. Чем выше значения каждого из параметров, тем больше цветов можно использовать в приложении. Например, если выставить значение каждого аттрибута равным **8**, то в программе можно использовать **16 777 216** оттенков цветов и **256** градаций прозрачности. Подробнее - [здесь (ru.wikipedia.org)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D1%86%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0).